# How to create landing page for amazon home?

Tags: magento2

My site is in magento 2.
We add M2E Pro for sell product on amazon & eBay.
We want when go on amazon the one landing page show first.
Then go for product.
Any one help me how to create one page which is our landing page for amazon home.